# Dropdown boxes from different models in a single view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Bear with me i am new to Asp.net MVC.

I have the following Models

```
public class District {
public int id{get;set;}
public String districtName{get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Tehsil> tehsil{get;set;} 
}

public class Tehsil{
public int id{get;set;}
public String tehsilName{get;set;}   
public virtual ICollection<UnionCouncil> uc{get;set;}
}

public class UnionCouncil {
public int id{get;set;}
public String ucName{get;set;}

}
public class Person{
public int id{get;set;}
public int name{get;set;}
public int districtId{get;set;}
public int tehsilId{get;set;}
public int UnionCouncilId{get;set;}

}

public class StorePerson{
public Person person{get;set;}
public District district{get;set;}
public Tehsil tehsil {get;set;}
public UnionCouncil unionCouncil {get;set;}

}
```

In my View i Pass the StorePerson Model. I want to Display a view Having all the attributes of the person model i.e id, name along with Dropdownboxes of District, Tehsil, UnionCouncil from which the User can select the appropriate value. I am stumped here at this point.

```
`@model DistrictExample.Models.StorePerson
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreatePerson";
}

<h2>CreatePerson</h2>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.person.name)


@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.person.districtId,new SelectList(m=>m)
```

How do i get the Dropdownbox for District, UnionCouncil, Tehsil in the view. The lambda m doesn't popout any model property. Is there a better way to do it. Or is there any problem with my existing approach.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> In your controller action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //All this is dummy data, you can bind Lists to Database data too.

        List<District> lstDistricts = new List<District>();
        lstDistricts.Add(new District() { id=1, districtName="test01" });
        lstDistricts.Add(new District() { id = 2, districtName = "test02" });

        List<Tehsil> lstTehsil = new List<Tehsil>();
        lstTehsil.Add(new Tehsil() { id = 1, tehsilName = "test01" });
        lstTehsil.Add(new Tehsil() { id = 2, tehsilName = "test02" });


        List<UnionCouncil> lstUnionCouncil = new List<UnionCouncil>();
        lstUnionCouncil.Add(new UnionCouncil() { id = 1, ucName = "test01" });
        lstUnionCouncil.Add(new UnionCouncil() { id = 2, ucName = "test02" });

        StorePerson sp = new StorePerson();

        Person p = new Person();
        p.name = "Zulu Khan";
        p.id = 1;
        p.districtId = 2;
        p.UnionCouncilId = 1;
        p.tehsilId = 2;
        sp.person = p;

        sp.Districts = lstDistricts;
        sp.Tehsils = lstTehsil;
        sp.UnionCouncils = lstUnionCouncil;

        return View(sp);
}
```

> In your view:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.name)
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.person.name)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.id)
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.person.id)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.districtId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.person.districtId, new SelectList(Model.Districts, "id", "districtName"))
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.tehsilId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.person.tehsilId, new SelectList(Model.Tehsils, "id", "tehsilName"))
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.UnionCouncilId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.person.UnionCouncilId, new SelectList(Model.UnionCouncils, "id", "ucName"))
</div>
```

**Here is its <kbd>[DotNetFiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rAFPyn)</kbd>**

---

> ### Edit

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //All this is dummy data, you can bind Lists to Database data too.

        List<District> lstDistricts = new List<District>();
        lstDistricts.Add(new District() { id=1, districtName="test01" });
        lstDistricts.Add(new District() { id = 2, districtName = "test02" });

        List<Tehsil> lstTehsil = new List<Tehsil>();
        lstTehsil.Add(new Tehsil() { id = 1, tehsilName = "test01" });
        lstTehsil.Add(new Tehsil() { id = 2, tehsilName = "test02" });


        List<UnionCouncil> lstUnionCouncil = new List<UnionCouncil>();
        lstUnionCouncil.Add(new UnionCouncil() { id = 1, ucName = "test01" });
        lstUnionCouncil.Add(new UnionCouncil() { id = 2, ucName = "test02" });

        StorePerson sp = new StorePerson(); 

        sp.Districts = lstDistricts;
        sp.Tehsils = lstTehsil;
        sp.UnionCouncils = lstUnionCouncil;

        return View(sp);
}
```

> In your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitActionName","Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {

<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.person.name)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.id)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.person.id)
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.districtId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.person.districtId, new SelectList(Model.Districts, "id", "districtName"))
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.tehsilId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.person.tehsilId, new SelectList(Model.Tehsils, "id", "tehsilName"))
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.person.UnionCouncilId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.person.UnionCouncilId, new SelectList(Model.UnionCouncils, "id", "ucName"))
</div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

Comment: But what if it is a new Record Create Form. i.e all the fields for Person would be blank and the Dropdown boxes populated from database